# Has anyone ever followed up their own missed free throw with a dunk?

Tags: basketball

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6ziQNSETe4) shows six instances of Michael Jordan following up a teammate's missed free throw with a dunk before he lands on the ground.

Has any player ever followed up their own missed free throw with a dunk before landing on the ground?

Comment: If only Shaq had hit the rim: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWbWyO4IWYQ

Comment: Would a standing dunk from the free throw line be physically possible?